# Run SharePoint Workflow when document is shared

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

Is there any way to run a SharePoint Workflow whenever any document is shared with any user?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to use OOB Share button to trigger a workflow. You need to build an alternate way for users to share files. When the user shares a file using the custom Share function you've built, you can trigger an event or start a workflow. Whereas, it may require some code.

Use REST API functions to [share documents](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.sg/2014/09/sharing-documents-with-sharepoint-rest.html) and start a workflow

REST API for starting a workflow:

```
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId='{Workflow Subscription ID}',itemId={ID of List item})
```

Another option, use SharePoint PnP.

Work with sharing via PnP:

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Sharing

Start a workflow instance via PnP Start-PnPWorkflowInstance：

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/Start-PnPWorkflowInstance.md